# Exporting Json data to XML File in Specific folder in angular

Tags: xml, angular, file-upload

I am setting up a **Xml Export** functionality, whose function is to convert Json data from DB to Xml and save as .xml file in specific folder.

I tried this link 
https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/16/implementing-file-save-functionality-with-angular-4/
but don't save as `.Xml` file.

I already converted the Json data to Xml data using this code

```
 this.ordertemplateService.GetOrderTemplate().subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        var jxmlparser = require('js2xmlparser');
        if (res != null) {
          result = jxmlparser.parse('OrderTemplate',res.data);
          console.log('back to xml -> %s', result);
}
```

and the Import too(XML to JSON).

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
       let xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"

       parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
         console.dir(result);
}
```

But don't know how to move forward. Please brainstorm me with your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save any file from frontend (Angular, Javascript etc) to a specific folder.

Create an API in backend(nodeJs, Php,Java etc), pass the xml Data to it, and then save the file in the desired location

Comment: Is it applicable Import too?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get, Import as in?

Comment: There are  codes , First Code for Json to Xml file (ur appraoch is applicable). For Second Code to read the Xml file to Json Data(Is ur approach applicable?)

Comment: Yes, you can read the xml file, convert it to json in the frontend and then pass the json data to the API

Comment: @Adritha Sharma Would you mind to look into this Question, which is related the this scenario? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708240/how-to-convert-class-array-to-xml-file-in-c